# Canada- Is work from home possible in Canada on Intra Company transfer visa?

Tags: working-visas, canada, ontario, british-columbia

Is work from home possible in Canada on Canadian ICT visa ([Intra Company transfer visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/exemption-codes/intra-company-transferees.html))?

Is it required for the work permit holder to work from an office (work permit location) even if the rest of the team works internationally and the only benefit would be helping the Canadian business and providing better round the clock support.

I am trying to understand the various federal/provincial rules relating to working from a specific location or not while on Work Permit? I could not find any mention about work from home in any of the help sections.

Are there any province specific rules in play? Target provinces are Ontario and BC.

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question for others:
It is not possible due to visa and legal guidelines. The work visa is associated with an office location where the employee is supposed to work and that location has to be definitive.

Comment: Can you add references to those *visa and legal guidelines*?

Comment: This was the reasoning mentioned to me by my Immigration team. I can check with them again but it was almost a couple of months old conversation.